# How can I populate a TableView in swift

Tags: tableview, swift4

So I am making an iOS app and it allows users to submit random entry’s to the member, it’s sort of like the Yolo app in many ways.

Now I have a web service setup to retrieve the data using HTTP POST requests and depending on the provided variables it will return the information it’s looking for.

I have no idea how I’m supposed to use a HTTP POST request to populate a UITableView in Swift. Can anyone help me out here, I’ve tried several times and several ways!

If it matters the two variables I need are 
type=X&identifier=y

NOTE: I AM NOT USING UITableView, I’m using the TableView within the View Controller

Comment: please provide the code you've tried and how the result differs from what you expected

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this kind of question is not really what we're here for, if you have code to share and an issue to help with please edit to include these details, otherwise, please read;  [help/dont-ask]  and [tour] then read over [ask]

Comment: @gmoshkin I don’t have immediate access to the code but I’ve tried parsing JSON and then taking the output and inserting it into a array.